# Javascript multiple if stops when true ignores everything else

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I have 25 IF statements that look at an image and execute different functions based upon its size and position relevant to the document size (canvas) in Photoshop.

I'm finding that when the script executes an if that's true, it then won't continue down the stack and execute other true ifs.

Is this a by-product of javascript, or en error on my part?

For example, both these ifs are true but it only executes the first one. If I run the script again, it then executes the second if. But I'd like to work out how to make the script run all ifs even when one is true.

```
//bottom edge only off doc
if (layerSmaller && layerLeftIn && layerRightIn && layerTopIn && layerBottomOut) {
    activeDocument.activeLayer.translate(0,docHeight-layerBottom+2);
    var percentageChange = ((docHeight / layerHeight) * 101);
    resizeBCenter(percentageChange) 
}

//layer smaller horizontally and right more than 65
if (layerWidth <= docWidth && layerTopOut && layerBottomOut && layerLeftOut && layerRightIn && Rmargin >= 65) {
   var percentageChange = ((docWidth / layerWidth) * 101);
resizeTLeft(percentageChange) 
  app.activeDocument.selection.selectAll();
  align('AdCH');
  align('AdCV');
  app.activeDocument.selection.deselect();
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: No, theoretically this should be running. I don't know about Photoshop's runtime, but you might have an error at execution of one of your ifs statements maybe?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've tried running it with just those two ifs and it still stops at the first. I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: Ok, still don't know what's going on but I've separated out the IFs into categories and made six separate scripts. Photoshop's batch actions can then run them in sequence and it's a lot easier to find any rogue code/amends to make.

Comment: Please provide a working example of code that can be tested

Comment: Does the first `IF` change values that will be tested in subsequent `IF`s? If yes, this may be the cause of the problem

Comment: They all link back to variables that are outside of the IF statements. Maybe it's possible that the script isn't re-evaluating the variables. So that a variable could be one value, which causes the IF statement to run, but then the next IF statement still sees the old variable value and skips it. Anyway, I've gotten around whatever issue there was by splitting them into separate scripts that are run as a batch action in Photoshop.